# Android LibGdx game screens load time

Tags: android, libgdx, screen

I need to improve the game screens load time for an Android game which uses the LibGdx game engine. I have implemented some classes (ImageProvider and SoundManager) that are responsible for preloading the assets and the audio part of the game.
So, the question is how do I load these game resources without influencing the load time between the game screens?

I have searched on internet regarding this issue and found some similar questions on Stack.

[How to decrease loading time of all Assets in libgdx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17488012/how-to-decrease-loading-time-of-all-assets-in-libgdx)

[AssetManager in LibGDX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9603907/assetmanager-in-libgdx)

Every answer on this issue would be very useful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: libGDX isn't game engine, it's framework. And please make your problem clearer because i didn't get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

As you have found the `AssetManager` may be what you're looking for, I have a splash screen which loads my whole assets, once they're loaded it sets the first game screen then I can jump between each of my game screens without reloading the assets each time, this resource was really helpful for me:

http://bitowl.de/day11/